# Dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10. Windows 7 isn't showing up

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I have Windows 7 loaded onto my computer. I have never used Ubuntu before and decided to do a dual boot. I installed it as a dual boot and I had the installer create the partition (I did not create it myself). When I booted it up, it shows Ubuntu 13.10 and Windows 7. I could access both, but Ubuntu's display was too big for my screen. I found a page that said to enter: 'sudo apt-get update' and 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade.' I did both and restarted. I got the black screen whenever I loaded Ubuntu, but I could still access Windows 7. I then put the install disk back in and said to reinstall Ubuntu with all settings staying the same. Now when I boot I get to the menu, and all Ubuntu options are there, but Windows 7 is not. I looked on the hard drive and Windows 7 is still there. I need help keeping the Ubuntu settings as is, and brining Windows 7 back to the boot menu. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, I understand how frustrating and complex GRUB can seem, and thus didn't vote your question down for being a duplicate.  However, in the future please try the search feature before asking questions.

Comment: I appreciate that. I will do more searching and researching before asking additional questions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot into Ubuntu os and run the below commands on the terminal,

```
sudo update-grub
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Now you will see windows entry on the grub.